Winsock.h External Dependencies not associating (or mis-associating) with members
I have been pulling an MFC-based application out into a purely console (standard windows libraries) application, and it has been mostly painless (if not tremendously tedious). I am currently trying to debug a class that handles connectivity via winsock.h.
Understand, very little of the code within this class is MFC dependent, so the Includes are fairly straightforward.  But the members being called are either being disassociating as a local variable or associating with multiple external dependency header files.  #include winsock.h is in the header of Connection.h in both the new and old versions of the app.
Note: The old MFC application runs perfectly.
How do I make sure the calls are associating with the appropriate external dependencies?
The errors I'm getting are:
struct ip_mreq mreq; -- Error 2079: Uses undefined struct. && Error C0070:  Incomplete type is not allowed



Sometimes ip_mreq is being seen as a locally defined struct...SOMETIMES. Error 2079 misrepresents it as Connection::connect::ip_mreq, the class/function in which I'm calling it. Clicking "peek definition" leads to the same line.  Other times it seems to be working and associates as a member of winsock.h.  The old MFC application associates it as a member of ws2ipdef.h.



IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL -- Error C0020: Identifier is undefined



Despite stating them as undefined, it actually finds 3 separate definitions.  Clicking "peek definition" leads to winsock.h, ws2ipdef.h, and wsipv6ok.h.  The old MFC application associates it as a member of ws2ipdef.h.




Please provide a [mre] that we can use to reproduce at least one of the errors.

For ip_mreq, the documentation says to include Ws2tcpip.h

Also, you should be using winsock2.h instead of winsock.h in modern code.

No updates in 20h, I vote to close for lack of a reproducible example.

@TedLyngmo I'm back.  I was pushed to another priority task until now.

@LazyBear Ok, but you still haven't provided a [mre] so my vote to close stands. It's going to take a long time to get your question answered if you show up once a week to check on it.

@IgorTandetnik Including Ws2tcpip.h seems to have solved the problem.  Thank you.  As I said, this was a previous MFC program that did not include that header despite the doc.  So it still strikes me as strange.

@TedLyngmo  I totally understand but what would you suggest in this circumstance?  I would love to make things easier for those willing to help. I tried and couldn't recreate the error as it is in a from-scratch example, a simple function in a class called from the main and it ran fine.  Unhelpful to anyone here, as it seemed there was no issue, but the error persisted in my much larger project nonetheless. Ws2tcpip.h fixed it (for now), but the original ran fine without it.

"I tried and couldn't recreate the error as it is in a from-scratch" - ok, that's unfprtunate, but still good in a way. Try adding to the example you prepared. If you eventually end up with code that works, compare the two versions to find what you missed in the first version. I've done that many times successfully.
